# Why do I keep getting Error 500 whenever I want to see how my agent works on google assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created an agent that answers simple questions.

I tried restarting my computer but I'm not able to see how it looks in the google assistant because of the above error.

When I'm in the Dialogflow editor, I click on the "See how it works in Google Assistant" link

[image]

But I get an error page

[image]

Comment: Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57003493/edit) to show the exact steps you're taking to "see how it looks" and possibly screen shots or other information showing the error? A 500 error indicates a problem with a web server, and it isn't clear how you are accessing that web server, or where exactly you're seeing the error 500.

Comment: [Here's the error that occurs]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXzia.png
[On clicking this( which is in the image)]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUv2J.png

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have this configured as an Actions on Google project. Try specifically setting up the Integration by clicking on the Integration menu item on the left, and then the "Integration Settings" link under the Assistant.

[image]

You should then be able to click on the "Test" link at the bottom of the window that popped up and it will take you to the simulator.

[image]

If this doesn't work, you may need to visit https://console.actions.google.com/ directly and open and test the project from there, or see if it generates a more useful error.